# Filtering and sorting Laravel collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-collection

I have this collection:

```
    'subscription_1' => [
        [
            'name' => 'test',
            'date' => '2020-12-10'
        ],
        [ 
            'name' => 'another test'
            'date' => '2020-12-10'
        ],
        [ 
            'name' => 'another test'
            'date' => '2020-12-11'
        ],
        [ 
            'name' => 'another test'
            'date' => '2020-12-11'
        ]
    ],
    'subscription_5' => [
        [
            'name' => 'test',
            'date' => '2020-03-04'
        ],
        [ 
            'name' => 'another test'
            'date' => '2020-03-04'
        ],
        [ 
            'name' => 'another test'
            'date' => '2020-08-06'
        ],
        [ 
            'name' => 'another test'
            'date' => '2020-08-06'
        ]
    ]
]
```

There's a lot of subscriptions.

The items inside are notifications. There could be 1 to 4 UNIQUE notifications and each one could repeat twice, i.e. up to 8 records.

So a single subscription could look like that:

```
       Notification 2020-08-06 15:13:05
       Notification 2020-08-06 15:13:05
       Notification 2020-09-04 12:05:03
       Notification 2020-09-04 12:05:03
       Notification 2020-10-05 14:03:05
       Notification 2020-10-05 14:03:05
```

I want to order each Subscription's notifications by date and then extract ALL first notifications in a `$first` collection, all second notifications in `$second` collection and so on up to fourth.

So in `$first` there should be the earliest sent notification for all subscriptions and any duplicates.

Comment: It seems you need to loop and use sortBy('date') and get the elements with shift()

Comment: so what have you tried till now and what error are you facing?

Comment: You description is confusing. You first give an example with dates from December, then March, then August. In the result I see January, February, March. I barely understood what you are trying to achieve. Could you please write an input and then the desired output. This task is trivial, you just need to be more specific.

Comment: @NikolayTraykov the second block is just an example of what could a block hold, not a result, maybe that's not clear enough, I'll try to rework it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try a loop with collect() :

```
foreach($notifications as $id => $notification) {
    $sorted = collect($notification)->sortBy('date');
    $first[$id] = $sorted->shift();
    $second[$id] = $sorted->shift();
    $third[$id] = $sorted->shift();
    $fourth[$id] = $sorted->shift();
}
```